# Retrieving javascript file content with Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to retrieve a JavaScript file content with Python. I thought that maybe `requests` would do the trick - perhaps it does but it's either not as straightforward as I thought or I'm doing something wrong.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(link)
```

The response I get is

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "&#91;no&#32;URL&#93;", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;3e1151c8&#46;1484072058&#46;308a223a
</BODY></HTML>
```

What I need it's the same that what this code does in php,

```
$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: "What I need it's the same that what this code does in php," What does this mean? Are you asking if the Python code would do the same thing as that PHP code?

Comment: I thought it would do the same, but it doesnt, or I'm doing something wrong. How do you get a javascript file content with requests or another python library?

Comment: I'm not able to answer your question, only to clarify it.

Comment: I had headers and other stuff initialized in the middle of the lines, that might be the problem because with a new requests object it is working, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a http get request

```
import urllib2
link = "http://whatever.com/your-file.js"
urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
```

The php code is using curl which is doing alot more than it looks